# Placing button or other widget at runtime on android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Quick question: at runtime I do a boolean check, if it returns true I would like to have two buttons in a relative layout on my MainActivity class. If its false I want to instead have two other widgets where those buttons would be (or near enough). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just those two alternatives put them both in your layout and hide / show the one you want. [View#setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

If you want it more dynamic you can add and remove widgets programmatically. [ViewGroup#addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29)

Modifying a `RelativeLayout` during runtime is quite complicated since you need to set all those layout parameters so you could add a simple layout like a `FrameLayout` in the place where the buttons should go and put them inside the frame. Has the advantage that you can setup all the relative layout parameters for the frame in xml.

Answer (score 1):

you could also implement a ViewSwitcher where a more complicated set of buttons/widgets can be switched out very easily with a single call to

```
  ViewSwitcher mViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher);

  if (some_logic == true) {
      mViewSwitcher.showNext();
  }
```

Set up your XML like this and the above will switch between the two LinearLayouts:

```
  <ViewSwitcher 
        android:id="@+id/viewswitcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            --- buttons, Views, whatever---
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            --- buttons, Views, whatever---
        </LinearLayout>
```